# Jquery addclass(), how to do with class conflict

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a navigation.
Here is CSS style

```
a:link.navA, a:visited.navA  
{  
    display:block;  
    width:120px;  
    color:#FFFFFF;  
    background-color:#003366;  
    text-align:center;  
    padding:4px;  
    text-decoration:none;  
    font-family:Calibri;  
}  
a:hover.navA  
{  
    background-color:#336699;  
}  
.selected  
{  
    background-color:#336699;  
}
```

When I select a button, I hope the background-color of that button will stay the different color like hover with others. When I use `addclass("selected")`, the selected button does not change color. I think it is because that the  will have two class "navA" and "selected", both of them define the background-color. My question is how to make selected class win.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You absolutly want to read this: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Answer (score 2):

You can add !important

```
.selected {
    background-color:#336699 !important;
}
```

This will make this rule override the others. However, it would be better if you just wrote better css.

**EDIT**

For example, if you want to have a different bg color for a button that has both .navA and .selected, you can write you CSS like this

```
.navA.selected {
    background-color:#336699;
}
```

Having it like this will tell the browser that any item with a class of navA AND selected should have a different bg. This way, you won't need to add the !important. Also, keep in mind that this will work ONLY if your element has both classes applied.

Comment: Could you give some hint? Do you mean that I can split a large class such as a:link.navA into many small classes? Then add several classes into element?

Comment: What I meant was you can easily fix it by targeting your CSS. User Capsule's link is a great example : http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: I've added an example to my answer so you can see.

Comment: Be careful with double classes selectors, it doesn't work in IE6. You'd better use some IDs in it to gain some specifity. The !important solution is good too but a little bit too radical ;-)

Comment: Yup, !important will work. But somewhere along the line you'll be wondering why you're getting one bg color when you've defined another only to realize there's an !important messing things up. Better CSS is always the solution.